# Unable to call React native function from Android

Tags: android, react-native, events

I am trying to call a function from native to react native . But I am getting this runtime exception

```
Tried to access a JS module before the React instance was fully set up. Calls to "
          + "ReactContext#getJSModule should only happen once initialize() has been called on your "
          + "native module.";
```

I am following Facebook react native documentation. And did went through many questions regarding this topic but nothing helps my issue.I am getting CatalystInstance null in getJsmodule.

Answer (score 0):

After debugging I got to know that I was missing current react context in MyActivity which is required to call `getJSModule` . So I extends my MainActivity from Activity to ReactActivity.